# Access a base class property in inheritance class

Tags: vb.net, inheritance, properties

I'm using the base class Button in VB.net (VS2017) to create a new class called CDeviceButton. The CDeviceButton then forms as a base for other classes such as CMotorButton, CValveButton.

I want to set the Tag property in the child class CMotorButton but access it in the constructor in CDeviceButton. Doesn't work for me. It turns up being empty.

The Tag is set in the standard property when inserting the CMotorButtom instance into a form.

I've also tried to ensure teh the parent classes' constructors are run by setting mybase.New() as the first action in each constructor but that didn't change anything.

Any ideas for improvements?

```
Public Class CDeviceButton
    Inherits Button
    Public MMIControl As String = "MMIC"

    Public Sub New()
        MMIControl = "MMIC" & Tag
    End Sub
End class

Public Class CMotorButton
    Inherits CDeviceButton

    Sub New()
        'Do Something
    end Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Base class' constructors are called first, before the child-class' constructor body. You could make the field a method: `Public Function GetMMIControl() As String
    Return "MMIC" & Tag?.ToString()
End Function`

Comment: Thanks, But the problem I am running into is that the Tag property that is derived from the base class Button isn't assigned a value until the constructor New() in my CMotorClass has finished. So it doesn't look like I can pass the Tag value until New() is done. What I did was to have a timer in CDeviceButton that start at the end of New() in CMotorButton. Tag is then available in CDeviceButton at the first tick of the timer (where I then stop the timer). I'll present the code if that is the final solution (doesn't make me that proud but might work for what I need....)

Answer (score 1):

When you try to concatenate Tag with a string, you are trying to add an object that is probably nothing. I set the Tag property first and used .ToString and it seems to work.

```
Public Class MyButton
        Inherits Button
        Public Property MyCustomTag As String
        Public Sub New()
            'Using an existing Property of Button
            Tag = "My Message"
            'Using a property you have added to the class
            MyCustomTag = "Message from MyCustomTag property : " & Tag.ToString
        End Sub
    End Class

    Public Class MyInheritedButton
        Inherits MyButton
        Public Sub New()
            If CStr(Tag) = "My Message" Then
                Debug.Print("Accessed Tag property from MyInheritedButton")
                Debug.Print(MyCustomTag)
            End If
        End Sub
    End Class
```

And then in the Form

```
Private Sub Test()
    Dim aButton As New MyInheritedButton
    MessageBox.Show(aButton.Tag.ToString)
    MessageBox.Show(aButton.MyCustomTag)
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, Your solution is not really what I'm aiming for. With setting the "Tag = my message" class MyButton the Tag remains at that value. I do not overwrite it in the InheritedButton class since the Tag property there isn't assigned before the New() method comes to an end. In the test() function I then only read the Tag from the MyButton Class, not from the InheritedClass as I was aiming for. See work around in comment on the first proposal.

Answer (score 0):

Below is my solution I came up with that works. Basically I make sure that all initialization has taken place before reading the Tag property. What I experienced is that the Tag property is empty until the New() in CMotorButton has completed, even though the Tag property has been set when creating the instance of CMotorButton in the Form. TimerInitate has a Tick Time of 500 ms.

Not the most professional solution but works for what I need at the moment.

Another option could be multi threading but that I haven't tried and leave that for future tryouts.

```
Public Class CDeviceButton
    Inherits Button
    Public MMIControl As String = "MMIC"

    Public Sub New()
        TimerInitiate = New Timer(Me)
    End Sub
    Private Sub TimerInitiate_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TimerInitiate.Tick
        If Tag <> Nothing Then
            TimerInitiate.Stop()
            MMIControl = "MMIC" & Tag
        End If 
    End Sub
End class

Public Class CMotorButton
    Inherits CDeviceButton

    Sub New()
        'Do Some stuff
        TimerInitiate.Start()
    End Sub
    Private Sub CMotorButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Click
End Class
```